# checking the object contents in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, json

I am writing a function in angular JS controller.

```
 $scope.names = $mmaGrades.getGradesTable(8, 14);
```

`getGradesTable` function returns JSON format data when I call it from rest client.

My Question is that how do I ensure that `$scope.names` storing the same JSON data. Is there any way to display the contents of `$scope.names` in controller?

Comment: You display the content on the view, not in the controller. But you can write `console.log($scope.names);` and you'll be able to see it in the console tab in the developer tools (For debug purposes)

Comment: Hi Alon i tried with the console but its not printing JSON data in console. Before displaying in the view i just wanted to check it in the controller

Comment: If `getGradesTable` return a promise, that it should be: `$mmaGrades.getGradesTable(8, 14).then( function(data) {  $scope.names = data; console.log(data);  } );`